# Maximal possible edges in graph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

A graph has 20 vertices. If two vertices are of same degree, they are not connected by an edge. Find the maximal possible number of edges in such a graph

I tried constructing it through diagram but am getting 1 vertex of 19 degree and rest of the vertices of other degree but am not able to proceed further. My approach is to find the number of vertices with degree satisfying the above condition and then using the handshaking lemma but am unable to proceed.

Can you please suggest some hints on the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that this is true, but let us assume that in an optimal solution, every vertex is adjacent to every other vertex of a different degree. So the optimal solution might be a [complete $k$-partite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_graph) with no two partition classes of the same size.

I made a computer search to find the repetition-free partition $20=n_1+\cdots +n_k$ that maximizes

$$|E|=\sum_{i<j} n_i n_j,$$

since this is the number of edges of the resulting graphs.

The result is $K_{2,3,4,5,6}$ is optimal with 155 edges.

---

Just in case you wonder, I used the following (quite unreadable) Mathematica code

```
MaximalBy[
    { #, Plus @@ Times @@@ Subsets[#,{2}] } & /@ 
        Select[IntegerPartitions[20],DuplicateFreeQ],
    Last
]
```

With output `{{{6,5,4,3,2},155}}`.

Comment: Admittedly "quite unreadable," yet very elegant and efficient ($+1$).

Comment: @M. Winter Thank you

Comment: can we after partitioning the into classes do by handshaking lemma for eg in the first partition it will have degree 18 second partition 17 and so do a product with the number of elements in the partition and add and then divide by 2 by applying handshaking lemma?

Comment: @tendo Sure. In a partition with $n_i$ elements, the sum over the degrees is $n_i(20-n_i)$, and by summing over all partitions you find $$6(20-6)+5(20-5)+4(20-4)+3(20-3)+2(20-2)=310,$$ which is twice 155.

Comment: @M.Winter Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that $155$ is not the maximum.  Via integer linear programming, I found that the maximum is instead $156$, attained by graphs with degree sequences $$(19,18,18,17,17,17,16,16,16,16,15,15,15,15,14,14,14,14,14,12),$$
$$(19,18,18,17,17,17,16,16,16,15,15,15,15,15,14,14,14,14,14,13),$$
and
$$(19,18,18,17,17,17,16,16,16,16,15,15,15,15,14,14,14,14,13,13),$$
and perhaps others.

Comment: Is there a chance you can describe these graphs more explicitly?

Comment: @M.Winter I think you can work them out by hand from the degree sequences. Take the first one. For $d\ge16$ each vertex of degree $d$ must be joined to all vertices of degree $\ne d$. The graph induced by the remaining $10$ vertices has degree sequence $(5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,2)$. Now it may be easier to think of the complementary graph, which has degree sequence $(4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,7)$, and is $K_4\cup K_5\cup K_1$ plus $8$ additional edges.