# Maximum Edges in a simple graph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

A graph has 45 vertices. If two vertices are of the same degree, they are not connected by an edge. Find the maximal possible number of edges in such a graph.

I have tried many different methods but not able to get it correct. Tried 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 as a partition, but obviously making a mistake. Can someone please help with it?

Comment: Have you tried some smaller examples? For starters, what is the maximal possible number of edges for a graph on $n$ vertices with $n\leq12$? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: I have, for n=3, the maximum edge is 2. For n = 4, max(|E|) = 3 ... for n = 20 max(|E|) = 155. But all were done using brute force. I am looking for a formula or program to count the edges for n=45.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  Is it an assignment, or something you came up with on your own?

Comment: I saw another question on similar lines with n=20 with an explanation and Mathematica code. When I tried the same solution for a number bigger than that I got stuck.
Now, I created a free trial account for Mathematics and ran the same code for n=45, I got the answer as 870. 
I am just looking for an explanation, which I can use without the coding. If possible.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question you saw?  This is interesting.

Comment: Link to that problem - [Above mention problem link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3855805/maximal-possible-edges-in-graph)

Comment: For $n=20$, the maximum is $156$, not $155$.

Answer (score 1):

Finally understood the solution. The following approach is working, although still does not make sense 100%. Never the less, the example graph is constructed as follows:

45 = 1 + 2 + ... + 9,

and we split the vertices into 9 groups and draw edges only between vertices of different groups.

The total edges are calculated between each combination.

1*(45-1) + 2*(45-2) + 3*(45-3) + ... + 9*(45-9) = 2|E|

which gives a total number of edges as:

|E| = 870

Comment: It makes a whole lot of sense. You want each vertex to have as many edges as possible. The maximum is 44, but you can't have more than one such vertex, for if you had two, they would be connected. Thus you resort to the next best option, which is 43, but you can't have more than 2 of these, so you move on...

Comment: Easier way to count those edges: $$|E|=\binom{45}2-\left[\binom12+\binom22+\binom32+\binom42+\binom52+\binom62+\binom72+\binom82+\binom92\right]$$ $$=\binom{45}2-\binom{10}3=990-120=870.$$