# Graph with 45 vertices, what is the maximum number of edges in such graph?

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I am a bit lost with this question.

**There is a graph with 45 vertices. If two vertices have the same degree, they are not connected by an edge. What is the maximal possible number of edges in such a graph?**

As far as I understand, if there are any 2 vertices with the same degree, they are not connected with the edge. But how do we calculate the exact number of edges?

Thanks!

Comment: As a starting point, consider a smaller case — say, a graph with five vertices, or with seven, where you can explicitly draw graphs and look for patterns.

Comment: Thanks, I have spend some time on it already, does it have anything to do with this: 3 vertices -> degrees (2,1,1), 4 vertices -> degrees (3, 2, 2, 1), 5 vertices -> degrees (4, 3, 2, 2, 1)...?

Comment: Hint. $$45=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9$$ $$\binom{45}2-\left[\binom92+\binom82+\binom72+\binom62+\binom52+\binom42+\binom32+\binom22+\binom12\right]$$ $$=\binom{45}2-\binom{10}3=990-120=770$$

Comment: For triangular numbers, the maximum seems to be https://oeis.org/A000914.  @bof you meant 870 instead of 770, and I confirm that 870 is optimal.

Comment: @Grimmie $(3,2,2,1)$ is not feasible.  For $n=4$, the maximum is instead $3$, from $(3,1,1,1)$.

Comment: @RobPratt Oops yes $990-120=870$ not $770$ that's what I get for trying to do all the arithmetic in my head which doesn't work so well any more. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856713/maximum-edges-in-a-simple-graph

Comment: @bof Thank you very much! It was really helpful! I am trying to understand this approach, so we take combinations of each connected component in order to calculate the maximum number of edges within this component, then we subtract the number of edges from the total maximum number of edges of 45 vertices? But why do we do it? Do we just subtract all potential pairs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum Edges in a simple graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856713/maximum-edges-in-a-simple-graph)